# How to perform tests based on the type of test in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given the following test file

```ruby
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe PurchaseCarService, type: :service do
  #...
end
```

How can I perform common tests for all specs of type `:service`?

I intend to have all (e.g.) Service objects enforce common Service standards.

Regards,

Comment: Have you read the docs on [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)?

Comment: I am currently using shared examples in some of my tests. I would need to add this code in all test files. I want something like [before suite hook](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-2/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#before/after-blocks-defined-in-config-are-run-in-order) with more flexibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [filtering](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/hooks/filters#filtering-hooks-using-symbols) I was able to run additional tests before each describes block with the context `type: :service`.

For example

```ruby
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.before(:example, type: :service) do
    # Run some common tests
  end
end
```